# How can i make a 3D model work as a button in AR

Tags: hyperlink, click, augmented-reality, aframe, 3d-model

I have started to look at Aframe to create a web based AR project but am not sure what I am doing.  My goal is to be able to spawn a 3D model in AR and make the model clickable or tap to open a hyperlink to a website.  Currently my code looks like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.3/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>     
    </head>
    <body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>              
        <a-scene embedded arjs cursor="rayorigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: #engine">
            <!-- Grab models from here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models -->
            <a-asset-item id="engine" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/2.0/2CylinderEngine/glTF/2CylinderEngine.gltf"></a-asset-item>             

            <!-- add the model -->                  
            <a-entity gltf-model="#engine" position="0 0 0" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" startEvents: "clicked"></a-entity>

            <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
        </a-scene>      

        <script>
            var toggleEl = document.querySelector('#engine')
            toggleEl.addEventListener('click', function (evt){
                toggleEl.emit("clicked");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

For now it is just a simple 'point camera at a marker, spawn a 3D model from a github repo, be able to click/tap on the model to open a hyperlink to a website' project but I am unable to get it to work.

What I am doing wrong? I thank you for any help that can be given.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible at present, there's no hit detection within webXR yet and regular user DOM events are disabled

https://aframe.io/blog/webxr-ar-module/

Comment: Thank you!  I'll keep an eye on it for now but I appreciate your information.

Comment: I see you're using ar.js you can please a touch event on a marker and not a model in this scenario 

https://medium.com/chialab-open-source/how-to-handle-click-events-on-ar-js-58fcacb77c4